# Printing values with variable spacing on each new line

Tags: c

I am trying to determine how to print out my values with a 2*(i-1) space on each new line.

I have seen code printed out in a perfect diagonal such as the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i=0,s=0;
    char c[50];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",c);

    while(c[i] != '\0')
        {
            s = i;
            while(s--)
            printf(" ");
            printf("%c\n",c[i]);
             i++; 
        }
        return 0;
}
```

However, I am looking for something a bit different where the following code prints out values with a 2*(i-1) space on each new line:

```
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
          char value = j + 'A';
          printf("%c", value);
        }
```

I want each value to have a 2*(i-1) space between them.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Show the exact ouput you want to get.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Updated, sir. Please ignore that the letters are different. I am just tackling the printing format right now.

Comment: Example: `printf("%*c", wid, ch);` will print `ch` in a field of width `wid`.

Comment: Perhaps `printf("%*c\n",2*i,c[i]);`?

Comment: @Weather Vane Appears you are 5 seconds smarter than I.

Comment: @chux I see you are more than a year and 20,000 rep smarter than me in SO!

Comment: @WeatherVane You solved it. Thank you. If you put it in an answer, I will accept it. Also, can you please explain why printf accepts three arguments when %c has an *?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: Please indent the code consistently.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  Never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control the field width easily in `printf` with a wildcard. When `*` is present at the beginning of the format (after `%`) it takes the next argument as its value, to format the field width. For example

```
printf("%*c", wid, ch);
```

will print `ch` right-justified in a field of width `wid` where `wid` is `int`. If you want it left-justified, add the `-` as usual (or supply a negative value in `wid`).

```
printf("%-*c", wid, ch);
```

Comment: Wonderful tip that I have to keep in mind for the future as well. Thank you, sir/madam.